# Count Records Prior to Date for Whole Year

Tags: sql

I have a historical database with about 9000 records with unique UserID and date they created an account CreatedDate that looks like this:

```
UserID     CreatedDate
1          5/12/2019
2          1/1/2018
3          4/2/2015
4          8/9/2016
.          ..
```

I would like to know how many accounts were created UP TO a certain date, but for multiple months.

For example, how many accounts were there in Jan 2020, Feb 2020, Mar 2020, so on and so forth.

The manual way would be to do this for each month but it would be tedious:

```
select count(*)
from SCHEMA
--KEEP REPLACING THE MONTH TO GET COUNTS
where CreatedDate <= '2020-01-31'
```

Just wondering if there is a more efficient way? A group by wouldn't work because it just totals for each month, but I'm trying to get a historical count. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Nguyen. The exact answer depends on your database vendor and version. Can you, please, assign more specific tags to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to need running total for each month. If so, you need `group by` to compute total counts per month and then you have to sum them using analytical `sum` function.

This is how you would do it in Postgres ([db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1f074ff8d96b5266f01f25e5e5aa6396)). Other vendors may differ in the way how month is extracted but the principle is same.

```sql
with schema(UserID,     CreatedDate) as (values
(1, date '2019-12-05'),
(2, date '2018-01-01'),
(3, date '2015-01-04'),
(4, date '2016-09-08')
)
select month, sum(cnt) over (order by month) from (
  select date_trunc('month', CreatedDate)::date as month, count(*) as cnt
  from schema
  group by date_trunc('month', CreatedDate)::date
) x
```

Note if data has gaps in month sequence and you want continuous sequence (for example all months between 2015-01 and 2019-12), you have to pregenerate calendar (relation with all months) and left join table `schema` to it. (It is not in my example yet because of YAGNI.)